# Pug 2 Template and Express. "view-engine" not recognised?

Tags: node.js, pug

I am attempting to use Pug (v2.0.0 b6) with Express (v4.14.0). I am under the knowledge that Pug follows Express template convention so integration would be as simple as:

`app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');`

**I render a pug page as follows:**

`app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('home', {
    var: "Var Placeholder!"
  });
});`

**However, upon making such a request, I get the following error:**

`error: Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62:11)
    at Function.render (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
    at /home/vagrant/frontend-web/app.js:42:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at Immediate.next (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/frontend-web/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15)
    at runCallback (timers.js:651:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:594:5)`

Is there something I missing?

Comment: is your template file name `home.pug` in the `views` directory?

Comment: Yes it is. I don't think the problem is filenames, I think it is the rendering engine.